# Applying Induction Hypothesis

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, induction

"Prove that for any even number $n\in\mathbb{N}, 2^{3n-1} + 5 \cdot 3^n$ is divisible by
$11$"

After proving the base case, I wrote my Induction Hypothesis as such:

Assume $2^{3k-1} + 5 \cdot 3^k$ is divisible by 11 for some even $k\in\mathbb{N}$.
Then, we must show $11 | 2^{3(k+2)-1} + 5 \cdot 3^{k+2}$.

These are the steps I took from here,

$2^{3k+5} + 5 \cdot 3^k \cdot 3^2$ 
$\Rightarrow 2^{3k-1} \cdot 2^6 + 5 \cdot 3^k \cdot 3^2$.

I'm a little stuck here algebraically, I'm not too sure how to apply the Induction Hypothesis in this position.

Answer (score 3):

To match the induction hypothesis, the next step would be

$$2^{3k-1}\cdot 2^6 + 5\cdot 3^k \cdot 3^2 = 2^6\left(2^{3k-1} + 5\cdot 3^k\right) +\left(3^2 - 2^6\right)5\cdot 3^k$$

Answer (score 1):

You can transform the question to :

For all natural  numbers $n≥1$, prove that :$$11\mid (2^{6n-1} + 5 \cdot 9^n)
$$

---

For $n=1$, the statement is obviously correct. To construct the inductive step, we assume that for $n=k$, the statement is correct :

$$2^{6k-1} + 5 \cdot 9^k=11m,\,m\in\mathbb Z$$

Then for $k+1$, you have :

$$
\begin{align}2^{6k+5}+5\cdot 9^{k+1}&=2^{6k+5}+9\left(11m-2^{6k-1}\right)\\
&=99m+2^{6k-1}\left(2^6-9\right)\\
&=99m+55\cdot 2^{6k-1}\thinspace .\end{align}
$$

By induction, you are done .